# how to set alert time interval notification when close app swift

Tags: swift, notifications, local

this my function .My function when open app and kill app before 10 sec it's show notification but I want to how to catch time interval when close app only

```
func showNotification(title: String, body: String) {
    // Configure the notification's payload.
    let content = contentNotification(title: title, body: body)
    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger) // Schedule the notification.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    // UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = (self as! UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate)
    center.add(request) { (error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle any errors
            print("err Noti = \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you describe it precisely?

Comment: I want to know set time interval for alert notification when we close app only

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution it's work for me 
I call my function in AppDelegate put call function in func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate.   See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
           // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates. 

     NotificationManagerLocal().showNotification(title: "terminate Alert", body: "0000")

       CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.saveContext()
       //        self.saveContext()
  }
```

then when we close app notification will be alert follow condition of trigger